# Looking up missing keys

Tags: sql, ms-access

Can I speed up this statement on Ms Access 2007?

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT p.zipcode, p.place FROM p) AS tmp
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
  (SELECT * FROM zipcodes WHERE 
    (tmp.zipcode=zipcodes.zipcode) AND (tmp.place=zipcodes.place));
```

I want to find the (zipcode, place) combinations in the `p` table that are not in the `zipcodes` table.

The `p`table is rather large, but when reduced to `tmp` has around 40.000 entries. The `zipcodes` table has around 15.000 entries. The `zipcodes` table is indexed on (zipcode, place).

It takes over one hour to get my result. Can I get it faster?  Can I see an execution plan in Access 2007? (I am not a regular Access user and also not a SQL expert.)

Kind regards,
Karsten.

Comment: There's no reason to do `NOT EXISTS (SELECT * ...` when returning NULL should do the exact same thing (you're just checking if a row exists that matches, the actual data stored in the row is ultimately irrelevant).

Comment: Do I understand you correctly that I could drop the EXISTS keyword, i.e. `WHERE NOT (SELECT *)...`?

Comment: No, you need the `exists` keyword. However, your `select` statement can simply be `select null` rather than `select *` because you're not actually interested in what the data in the row is, only that no row matches your criteria.

Comment: I don't know about Access, but SQL Server doesn't care about the column list in an `EXISTS` subquery (and hasn't for a decade?). It used to be that people had to use `SELECT 1` or `SELECT NULL` for optimization, but that's no longer necessary. As I said, I don't know about Access though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can LEFT JOIN the two tables and exclude the matching rows from the result set.  With the zipcodes table indexed on zipcode and place, this could be much faster than what you have now.  Hopefully fast enough you need not resort to creating an intermediate temporary table.

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.zipcode, p.place
FROM p LEFT JOIN zipcodes AS z ON (p.place = z.place) AND (p.zipcode = z.zipcode)
WHERE (((z.zipcode) Is Null));
```

**Edit**: You asked to see an execution plan.  Start with this article on TechRepublic: [Use Microsoft Jet's ShowPlan to write more efficient queries](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/use-microsoft-jets-showplan-to-write-more-efficient-queries/5064388)  You can also find more information by searching the web for "Jet ShowPlan".

Comment: This is very fast and in my opinion, most elegant. Thanks!

Comment: A JOIN is always preferable to a NON IN or NOT EXISTS, because in Jet/ACE, JOINs always use the indexes on both sides of the comparison, whereas sometimes with the NOT it uses it on only one side. Frankly, I only use subqueries that way when I need an editable recordset -- otherwise I'll use a JOIN.

Answer (score 1):

First, I would create a 'real' table `tmp` instead of using it in this way. This alone may already help (not sure). Second, I would ensure there is an index on zipcode in the table `p`, and if this doesn't help, also on the table `tmp`. If this still doesn't help, also create an index on the combination of (zipcode, place) on `zipcodes`.

Comment: Right. Working with the real table speeds up the query considerably (<10s).Thanks!